# link error on examples, when trying to compiling VTK to use static run time library

Tags: c++, linker-errors, vtk

I want to compile VTK so it uses static run time library ( /Mt and /MTd in visual studio) instead of dynamic run time library (/Md and /MDd) in visual studio.

to do this, I changed the CmakeLists files that come with VTK and add these lines to it:

```
if (MSVC)
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE} /MT" )
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG}  /MTd" )
endif (MSVC)
```

when I tried to build the samples, I am getting this linker errors:

```
Error   101 error LNK2005: "private: __cdecl type_info::type_info(class type_info const &)" (??0type_info@@AEAA@AEBV0@@Z) already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(typinfo.obj)   C:\Local\VTK-6.2.0\build\Examples\Tutorial\Step3\Cxx\MSVCRTD.lib(ti_inst.obj)   Cone3
```

if I remove the part that I added to cmakelists, it compiles and runs all examples.

As my application already uses static libraries, I need to make sure that VTK also uses static library.

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The direct approach would be to ignore-default-library MSVCRTD.lib - but I would advise on understanding the issue before stomping it like that.

You can build with /VERBOSE, search the output for MSVCRTD.lib and arrive at the first location that loads it.  Potentially it is a 3rd party lib used by the example, or a different project you had to switch.